# What does it mean when someone says "it is way too off the mark"

Tags: word-meaning

I read here and there someone saying "it is not far off the mark".

Someone else said *that is way too off the mark*.

My perception is that it means: it is somehow relates to what mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

"Off the mark" (and "on the mark") are idioms from archery. If your arrow doesn't hit the bull's-eye, it landed *off the mark*. "Off the mark," then, means *inaccurate*.

From my experience, it tends to be a polite euphemism. For example, suppose someone says,

> There are no better widgets than the Whamdoodle widgets.

and I disagree. I could reply:

> No! You're wrong about that.

However, that language is contentious and confrontational. Unless said good-naturedly among friends, it could be considered impolite.

Instead, I might say:

> I think you're off the mark there.

One thing that makes *off the mark* a little more polite: just because someone is off the mark, doesn't mean they've completely missed the target.

[image]

So, on the Stack Exchange, *off the mark* would be a good idiom to use when you think that someone's response has merit, but you also think there is something amiss in the answer.

NOAD defines *amiss* as "not quite right." That would be similar to "off the mark."

***Way** off the mark*, then, would mean "completely off target." That would be more appropriate when you want to point out a major error.  In that context, *way* means: *at considerable distance or extent; far.*